# Nested GridView Problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to nest one gridview within another, but I cannot get the data to populate in the second grid view. I am getting an error when trying to set the data source of the second data grid (saying it is null). Can anyone help? 
Here is the aspx page:

```
<div id="divSource" runat="server" align="center">
<asp:GridView ID="Source" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="sourceLineItem"  CSSClass="viewSourceGrid" OnRowDataBound="PopulateDateCodes">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField InsertVisible="False" HeaderStyle-Width="70px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label CssClass="sourceHeader" runat="server" Text= '<%# "Source: " + (Container.DataItemIndex + 1).ToString() %>'> </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="nfdBroker" HeaderText="NFD/Broker" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="nfdBroker" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="locationDescription" HeaderText="Material Location" SortExpression="materialLocation" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="origPkg" HeaderText="Original Packaging?" SortExpression="origPkg" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="oemCC" HeaderText="OEM C of C? " InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="oemCC" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="minBuyQty" HeaderText="Minimum Buy Qty" SortExpression="minBuyQty" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="deliveryInfo" HeaderText="Delivery" SortExpression="delUOM" />

        <asp:TemplateField InsertVisible="False" HeaderText="Date Codes" >
            <ItemTemplate>               
                <asp:GridView ID="DateCodeGrid" runat="server" InsertVisible="False" DataKeyNames="dateCode"  CSSClass="viewSourceGrid" >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="dateCode" SortExpression="dateCode">
                            <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and then here is the code behind:

```
    public partial class Controls_ViewSource : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    //Set the Source Line Item
    public int SourceLineItem { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SourceLineItem = SourceLineItem;
        RequestDB db = new RequestDB();
        DataSet sources = db.GetSource(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["requestNumber"]), SourceLineItem);
        Source.DataSource = sources;
        Source.DataBind();

    }

    protected void PopulateDateCodes(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        RequestDB db = new RequestDB();
        int index = e.Row.RowIndex;
        GridView gv = (GridView)Source.Rows[0].FindControl("DateCodeGrid");
        //int sourceLineItem = int.Parse(Source.DataKeyNames[0].ToString());
        //Response.Write(Source.DataKeyNames[0].ToString());
        DataSet dateCodes = db.GetDateCodes(71);
        gv.DataSource = dateCodes;
        gv.DataBind();

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us also the code for `db.GetDateCodes` ? I suspect that you are not linking in your nested data

Comment: Also, your GV population code is strange. It looks like you are not populating the gridview, but only the first nested gridview inside the first row? The outside gridview needs to be databound first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to find the nested grid view in the row that is being data bound:

```
GridViewRow row = e.Row;
```

You need to make sure you are only doing this for data rows, not header or footer rows:

```
if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
  // Find the nested grid view
  GridView nested = (GridView)row.FindControl("DateCodeGrid");

  // The rest of your code for binding the nested grid view follows here
}
```